# Make: *** [processor.out.c] Error 1

Tags: centos, php5, php-fpm, xcache

CentOS
PHP-FPM

```
'./configure'  '--enable-fpm' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl=/usr/local/lib' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--with-kerberos' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-mhash' '--with-mysql' '--with-mysqli' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pear=/usr/local/lib/php' '--with-png-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--with-pspell' '--with-sqlite=shared' '--with-tidy' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xsl' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--with-openssl' '--with-iconv' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-zip' '--enable-wddx'
```

Trying to install xcache but I keep getting these errors:

```
root@www1 [/usr/src/xcache-3.0.3]# make
/usr/bin/m4 -B 102400 -D srcdir='`'"/usr/src/xcache-3.0.3'" -D builddir='`'".'"  /usr/src/xcache-3.0.3/processor/main.m4 > ./processor.out.c.tmp
/usr/bin/m4: Warning: `m4 -B' may be removed in a future release
AUTOCHECK INFO: runtime autocheck Disabled (optimized build)
AUTOCHECK INFO: zend_compiled_variable: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK ERROR: ==== calc zend_try_catch_element =================
AUTOCHECK expected: "try_op","catch_op","finally_op","finally_end"
AUTOCHECK missing : "finally_op" "finally_end"
AUTOCHECK INFO: zend_brk_cont_element: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: HashTable: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: zval: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: zend_arg_info: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: zend_constant: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: zend_property_info: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: zend_trait_method_reference: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: zend_trait_alias: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: zend_trait_precedence: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: zend_class_entry: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: znode: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: zend_op: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: zend_literal: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK ERROR: ==== calc zend_op_array =================
AUTOCHECK expected: "type","function_name","scope","fn_flags","prototype","num_args","required_num_args","arg_info","refcount","opcodes","last","vars","last_var","T","nested_calls","used_stack","brk_cont_array","last_brk_cont","try_catch_array","last_try_catch","has_finally_block","static_variables","this_var","filename","line_start","line_end","doc_comment","doc_comment_len","early_binding","literals","last_literal","run_time_cache","last_cache_slot","reserved"
AUTOCHECK missing : "nested_calls" "used_stack" "has_finally_block"
AUTOCHECK INFO: xc_constinfo_t: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: xc_op_array_info_detail_t: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: xc_op_array_info_t: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: xc_funcinfo_t: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: xc_classinfo_t: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: xc_autoglobal_t: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: xc_compilererror_t: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: xc_entry_data_php_t: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: xc_entry_t: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: xc_entry_php_t: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK INFO: xc_entry_var_t: processor looks good
AUTOCHECK ERROR: ==== store zend_try_catch_element =================
AUTOCHECK ERROR: ==== store zend_op_array =================
AUTOCHECK ERROR: ==== restore zend_try_catch_element =================
AUTOCHECK ERROR: ==== restore zend_op_array =================
AUTOCHECK ERROR: ==== dprint zend_try_catch_element =================
AUTOCHECK ERROR: ==== dprint zend_op_array =================
AUTOCHECK ERROR: ==== dasm zend_try_catch_element =================
AUTOCHECK ERROR: ==== dasm zend_op_array =================
AUTOCHECK ERROR: ==== asm zend_try_catch_element =================
AUTOCHECK ERROR: ==== asm zend_op_array =================
make: *** [processor.out.c] Error 1
```

I did the following:

```
~/src $ wget http://... (the release url)
~/src $ tar -zxf xcache-*.tar.gz
~/src $ cd xcache
~/src/xcache $ phpize
~/src/xcache $ ./configure --enable-xcache
~/src/xcache $ make
```

Comment: What is your OS? Distribution? How did you install PHP?

Comment: PHP-FPM from source.CentOS

Comment: Which ones? 5.x or 6.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.5, [this bug report response probably has your answer](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=713519#10).

> Not sure if the cause is same, but xcache 3.0.x does not support PHP
>   5.5 we currently have in unstable, so it's anyway broken. This will be
>   fixed in 3.1 release.